# Show $(E|X|^2)/(E|X^2|) \leq P(X \not =0)$

Tags: probability, expected-value, probability-inequalities, bounds

I'm looking to show this inequality is true, and in turn use it to conclude the second moment method's bound.

Show that $\frac{E|X|^2}{E|X^2|} \leq P(X \not =0)$.

Again, I'm not supposed to use second moment method, I am going to use this to show the second moment method. Anyone have any tips? All my arguments are circular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By Holder's Inequality:

$E[|X|]=E[|X|1_{X\neq 0}]\leq \sqrt{E[|X|^2]E[1_{X\neq 0}^2]}=\sqrt{E[|X|^2]P(X\neq 0)}.$

Comment: Thank you! This is def it. I have learned Holders, but not in the way you presented it. The 1_x!=0 notation confuses me. Could I just define that as another variable Y such that Y is 0 when x is not, and Y is 1 when x is 0?

Comment: @Ralph: $1_{A}(\omega)$ is known as indicator function notation. This function is 1 when $\omega \in A$ and 0 otherwise. So $1_{X\neq 0}$ is equal to 1 precisely when $X(\omega)\neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up for me!